# Separar string variable por comas en columnas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo una metrica en una tabla que se compone de strings largos separados por comas y que varian como por ejemplo:

`(Carmen,Luis,Maria,Jose Miguel)`

`(Monica,Sergio,Carmen,Pedro,Claudia)`

`(Laura,Monica,Carmen)`

Y me gustaria separarlos por columnas cada elemento para asi ver las relaciones, es decir, ver Carmen cuantas veces aparece con Sergio (solo una vez) o con Monica (dos veces). Pero con SUBSTRING_INDEX no consigo sacarlos separados ya que si pongo SUBSTRING_INDEX(metrica, "1",2) me daria "Carmen,Luis".... y no me sirve para poder ver relaciones. ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Mil gracias!

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser totalmente en MySQL o puedes apoyarte en PHP o Python? A ver si esto te ilumina el camino: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599

Comment: @DavidJP Pues querria hacerlo en MySQL pero se que no se pueden hacer bucles ni nada por el estilo. Si lo hago con python como podria conectarme las bases de datos relaciones que tengo en MySQL con python? Gracias!